# why vue component css extract into one entry css file when there are tow entry

Tags: webpack, vue.js

i set webpack with tow entry

```js
entry: {
    index: './src/view/index/',
    home: './src/view/home/',
}
```

entry index had import A.component

entry home didn’t import A.componet. but its async chunk had import A.componet，like this:

```js
const vipInvite = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "vipInvite" */ '@/view/index/vip/invite/indev.vue')
// vipInVite import A.componet
```

here is the question:

after webpack build，i got tow css

1. index.css which included  A.componet’s css
2. home.css which didn’t include A.componet’s css. the async chunk aslo didn’t include A.component’css.

index.css and home.css are used in different html.

when i load the html which use home.css，A.componnet’s css wasn't loaded.

did i miss something? thank you guys！

Comment: I believe you have a typo in your last sentence.

Comment: Oh my...tks dude